# How to get defaut value in location of branch or customer in Acumatica

Tags: cloud, acumatica, erp

I am doing some query to get report by using sql script. I would like to get the default location of branch or customer by using field "Is Default" on the screen. But I dont see that field is value is stored in database. I guess that it would be displayed by using mask.
Please help me about that. 
Thanks for your support

Comment: I don't see an "Is Default" option anywhere on the customer screen. Can you include the location of that option?

Comment: you should check it in tab customer location

Comment: Judging by the PX.Objects.CR.Location.Ext.Address DAC, I can confirm IsDefault is not stored in the database. It is determined during run time. I'm not sure how it is done at this time, but if I figure something out, I will post an update.

Comment: Thanks you @EricP.